# for loop output

Tags: for-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm having trouble coding a simple task for loop. What I need for the loop to do is as follows:

1) Prompt the user asking what's 50 + 10 =

2) If the user enters the wrong answer a warning message will pop up saying they have 2 more attempts

3) Once the user exhausts all of their attempts a different message will pop up saying you have no more attempts

This is what I have been able to come up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int attempt = 1;
int answer = 60;

for( attempt = 1; attempt < 0; --attempt)

System.out.print(" 50 + 10 = ");
answer = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();

    if( answer != 60)
    {
        System.out.printf( "Invalid! Try Again! %d attempt(s) left! ", attempt);

        System.out.print( "\n50 + 10 = " );
        answer = input.nextInt();
    }

        if( attempt == 0)
        {
            System.out.print( "Sorry!  You have no more attempts left!" );
        }

System.exit(0);
}
```

If I change the value of the control variable from 1 to say 2 it'll print 50 + 10 = 50 + 10 =

And when I run the program it'll output with 0 attempts left rather than 2 attempts, then 1, then Sorry message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here...I have modified it to some extent...

```
for( attempt = 1; attempt >= 0; --attempt)
        {
        System.out.print(" 50 + 10 = ");
        answer = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

            if( answer != 60)
            {

                if(attempt!=0)
                    {
                     System.out.printf( "Invalid! Try Again! %d attempt(s) left!\n ", attempt);
                        continue;
                    }
                else
                     System.out.print( "Sorry!  You have no more attempts left!" );

            }
                System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: This did work, but I do have a question regarding the control variable. When I changed it to 2 or 3 why did it make a copy of my prompt for whatever number I put there?

So for instance in my code a 2 would make 50 + 10 = 50 + 10 =

Comment: Its because your for loop never opens.....there are no braces({}) to include the statements which for loop will execute....hence it executes only the first statement...

Comment: Ah, OK. This dumb book has examples of for loops and none of them use braces, so I have been leaving them off. Thanks for the help and your time!